# Client's objects movement not syncing across the Network

Tags: android, networking, multiplayer, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2-player android game using UNET. Now, all the movements of the host's objects are syncing across the network therefore it's working fine. But when the object on the client's side moves, it moves but it doesn't move in the host's screen. Therefore, the movement is not syncing.

I already attached NetworkIdentity, NetworkTransform, and PlayerController script to it. As well as the box collider (for the raycast).

The server and the client has the same script in the PlayerController but the only difference is, host could only move objects with `Player` tags and objects with `Tagger` tags for the client.

```
void Update () {
        if(!isLocalPlayer){
            return;
        }

        if(isServer){
        Debug.Log("Server here.");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        { 

            Vector2 cubeRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); 
            RaycastHit2D cubeHit = Physics2D.Raycast(cubeRay, Vector2.zero); 

            if (cubeHit) 
            { 
                if(cubeHit.transform.tag=="Player")
                {
                    if (this.target != null) 
                    { 
                        SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>(); 
                        if (sm != null) { sm.enabled = false; } 
                    } 
                    target = cubeHit.transform.gameObject; 
                    selectedPlayer(); 
                }

            } 
        }
    }

    if(!isServer){
        Debug.Log("Client here.");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        { 

            Vector2 cubeRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); 
            RaycastHit2D cubeHit = Physics2D.Raycast(cubeRay, Vector2.zero); 

            if (cubeHit) 
            { 
                if(cubeHit.transform.tag=="Tagger")
                {
                    if (this.target != null) 
                    { 
                        SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>(); 
                        if (sm != null) { sm.enabled = false; } 
                    } 
                    target = cubeHit.transform.gameObject; 
                    selectedPlayer(); 
                }

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `(!isServer)` to identify client because `isClient` sometimes doesn't work fine on my project. I also tried using it again to test it out, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use tags to move players this one script PlayerController is enough using only isLocalPlayer check and try disabling this script using !isLocalPlayer on both clients. Use this for reference http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSetup.html and check thier sample tutorial

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed. And I already used `!isLocalPlayer`. If I don't use tags, both players can control all the characters. Each player have multiple characters. I'm really confused about networking.

Comment: try using hasAutority and disable palyercontroller on others

Comment: I tested it out again now and I've observed that if I put a client's object on the Player prefab in the Spawn Info, it is syncing but the other objects are not. I also tried putting the other prefabs on the _Registered Spawnable Prefabs_, but still won't work. But this only happens on the client side.